# apply group by on one column based on the condition of other column

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a preview of the dataframe:

[image]

**The output I need:**

```
AGE
0-17     0.0
18-25    4598.0
26-35    24696.0
36-45    62385.0
46-50    0.0
51-55    0.0
55+      0.0
 Name: PURCHASE, dtype: float64
```

**The output I'm getting with my code**

```
AGE
18-25     4598
26-35    24696
36-45    62385
Name: PURCHASE, dtype: int64
```

```
purchaseDataFrame=pd.read_csv(purchasePath)
val='P00054142'
dfl=purchaseDataFrame[purchaseDataFrame['PRODUCT_ID']==val]
# print(dfl)
x=dfl.groupby('AGE').sum()
# print(x)
print(x['PURCHASE'])
```

The above is the code I tried don't have any clue how to get the desired output.

Comment: Can you try and edit your question please? I can't really understand what you're looking for.

Comment: is there any way i can reach your personally?

Comment: When you say age group 0 what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
val = ['0-17','18-25','26-35','36-45','46-50','51-55','55+']
print(x['PURCHASE'].reindex(v, fill_value=0)
```